# Is it possible to decrease min.insync.replicas?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm planning to run a Kafka cluster in a production environment. Before deploying the cluster, I try to find the best configuration to ensure HA and data consistency.

I read in the official doc that it is not possible to reduce the partition replication factor, but what about the `min.insync.replicas`? When I decrease the value on a test environment I don't see any differences when I look at topics description. After changing the value from 3 to 2, I still have 3 ISR. Is it because it's a min value or because the configuration change is not taken into account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to reduce (or in general change) the `min.insync.replicas` configuration of a topic.

However, as you were looking for the best configuration to ensure high availablity and data consistency, it would be counter-intuitive to reduce the value.

There is a big difference between ISR (in sync replicas) and the setting `min.insync.replicas`. The ISR shown in the `kafka-topics --describe` just tells you how healthy the data in your topic is and if all the replicas keep up with the partitions leader.

On the other hand, the `min.insync.replicas` works together with a KafkaProducer writing to the topic with that setting. It is described on the official Kafka docs on [TopicConfigs](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#topicconfigs) as:

> When a producer sets `acks` to "all" (or "-1"), `min.insync.replicas` specifies the minimum number of replicas that must acknowledge a write for the write to be considered **successful**.

To emphasize again, if you are looking for high availabilty and consistency it is best to set `acks = all` in your producer while at the same time keeping the `min.insync.replicas` high.

Comment: I plan to set up min.insync.replica to 2 and replication factor to 3 to manage one broker outage (3 brokers on 3 machines on 3 AZs). Thank you very much, I understand better!